# Authenticating users to a web application via twitter

Tags: java, jquery, servlets, twitter, twitter-oauth

Hello I am building a app and i am novice to api's and all. I want provide authenticate my users to access my web app via twitter am using servlets and mysql at the back end and jquery and javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter uses [OAuth](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_faq), not OpenID, and I believe what you are looking to do is called *Sign in with Twitter*, which is outlined [here](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/sign_in_with_twitter). In order to perform *Sign in with Twitter* you need to understand OAuth, and have an OAuth implementation you can utilize. A list of libraries that support OAuth is located [here](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_libraries).